# Text on Ask Ubuntu overwrites other text

Tags: bug, design

This occurred today and at other times. Anyone else experienced it?

It has occured on 16.04 and 18.04.(Ubuntu Mate)

> [image]

Comment: They're working on a new site theme. Might be related. I've had some graphical issues with the top bars myself.